# Can somebody check this "serial downvoting" for me?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

Just looking at my reputation history, I see the following, which didn't get triggered in the detection script.

[image]

I know it's only 6 points (I don't suspect the accept/unaccept entry), but it looks suspicious to me as these are quite old questions/answers and the downvotes are all within a short time.

If anyone can shed any light on whether or not this is a bug in the detection script, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Downvote troll. Frustrated user. I think that great many users, especially those with high (>1000) rep suffer from those things. I treat it as mosquito bites: irritating but harmless in the long run. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes, I agree, I'm not upset about it (I gained much more than I lost that day) just thinking it should have been picked up by the script (algorithm unknowable!) ...

Comment: Nah, the script is there for bigger fish. Maybe if the downvoter did it for more than one user, maybe only if more than X (5? 6?) posts.

Comment: [Mosquito bites aren't always harmless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaria) @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: @Yannis fair point! Guess you mean Post Ban disease? :{

Comment: @sha When mosquitos bite, we should swat them!

Comment: @Yannis [Mosquito bites can be more dangerous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengue_fever) :P

Comment: @911 [Mosquito bites can be yet more menacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_encephalitis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that ideally, you alert us to by raising a flag or [contacting us directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact/other). I did check, but there's not a pattern that I'd really consider *serial*. At this point, I'd call it interesting, if not concerning, but it's not really actionable at the moment.

If it *continues*, please reach out to us. You can flag any of your posts as 'other' and inform the moderators that you suspect targeted voting over time, or just contact us as I described. I'm sorry that I can't give you a more final conclusion, but there's simply not enough there to differentiate malice from benign behavior. Unfortunately, I can't really go into greater detail - voting is strictly anonymous and confidential.

Sorry about the annoyance, but at this particular point in time, the best advice I can give you is shrug it off and keep an eye on it.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I've shrugged off and will stay alert - I was more concerned about a bug in the script. Thanks for the feedback, I will do as you suggest in future.